# What's the difference between <<-EOH and <<~EOH (if there is any) in ruby

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, heredoc, adobe-brackets

Is there any difference between `<<-EOH` and `<<~EOH`?

I question that because Brackets doesn't highlight properly the ruby/chef code when I use `<<-EOH` and I have already tons of code running in production that way. So it would be impossible to approve my PR when everything is working fine and the only problem is my editor can't highlight.

When I switch `<<-EOH` by `<<~EOH` the code is properly recognized by Brackets and the code highlight works fine.

Is that a bug on Brackets or `<<-EOH` is wrong?

```rb
bash 'run_a_command_block' do
  code <<-EOH
    /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/a_regular_script.py
  EOH
  action :nothing
end
```

Comment: https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/11/ruby-heredoc/ and many others. The web is your friend.

Comment: [There is plenty of information about ruby syntax on the internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+<<~). What you're actually complaining about though, it seems, is a syntax highlighting issue in your version of `Brackets`. Are you running the latest version? (If not, update it. Did that fix it?) Has anyone reported the issue already? (If not, you could report it yourself.)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain what, *precisely* is unclear to you about the documentation of heredocs in Ruby. This has three advantages: 1) That way, the Ruby developers can improve the documentation so that future developers don't fall into the same traps that you did. Make the world a better place! 2) It tells what you did and didn't understand about the documentation, so that we don't waste our timing repeating in our answers something you already know or something you don't understand. 3) It shows that you have done thorough research to try and answer the question yourself.

Comment: If `<<~EOH` is highlighted correctly, and `<<-EOH` is not, then your editor is the culprit. The "squiggly" heredoc was introduced after the "straight" one. Ruby versions understanding the newer variant will understand the older.

Answer (score 3):

The squiggly heredoc will unindent the content to the level of the least indented row:

```
straight = <<-END_OF_TEXT
      Hello.

    This is:
      a regular dash.
END_OF_TEXT

squiggly = <<~END_OF_TEXT
      Hello.

    This is:
      using the squiggly dash.
END_OF_TEXT

separator = "-" * 30

puts separator
puts straight
puts separator
puts squiggly
puts separator
```

This outputs:

```
------------------------------
      Hello.

    This is:
      a regular dash.
------------------------------
  Hello.

This is:
  using the squiggly dash.
------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer. They do different things. The straight one keeps the structure of the multi line string (line changes) while the squiggly concatenates every line as they were a single line.

Please refer to:
https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/multiline-strings-ruby-2-3-0-the-squiggly-heredoc#disqus_thread

I will check if I have the latest Brackets version. If yes, I open a ticket as suggested.

Thanks you all.

Comment: That's not correct.

The modifiers alter the indentation. When using the squiggy  `<<~END_OF_TEXT` the content is un-indented to the depth of the least indented row, meaning.

Comment: Lines are not concatenated to a single line like you state here.